# How to implement node-lru-cache?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, caching

I've developed a real time app with **Node.js**, **Socket.io** and **mongodb**. It has a certain requirement that when a user loads a specific page then some 20000 points with x and y coordinates which are between 2 specific dates are fetched from mongodb and rendered on the map to client. Now if the user again reloads, the process is repeated. I'm confused how to insert these points in cache with what key so that when user reloads, the values from cache are fetched easily with the key.
Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could

1. completly write your own caching layer
2. use an existing caching library here (e.g.
   [lru-cache](https://npmjs.org/package/lru-cache)-module by isaacs,
   which probably is the most popular in this field)
3. could use [redis](https://redis.io) as a cache (there is the
   ability to set a TTL for inserted docs) there is already a
   [mongoose-redis-cache](https://npmjs.org/package/mongoose-redis-cache)-module,
   maybe that helps

and potentially x other solutions. it depends on the scale of your data/number of reqests and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The caching is something your database does for you in this case. MongoDB relies on the operating system's memory-mapped I/O for storage. A general purpose OS will usually keep the most frequently used pages in memory. If you still want to use an additional cache, the obvious key to use for coordinates would be a [Geohash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash).

Answer (score 0):

This library [runtime-memcache](https://github.com/tusharf5/runtime-memcache) implements `lru` and a few other caching schemes in javascript. Works with Node.js and written in Typescript.

It uses modified Doubly Linked List to achieve O(1) for `get`, `set` and `remove`.